# How to take input from user in structure in Solidity?

Tags: structure, solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0<0.9.0;
contract emp
{
    struct Details
    {
        string name;
        uint id;
        string post;
    }
    Details dtl;

    function setDetails(string a, uint b, string c) public
    {
        dtl=Details('a' , b , 'c');
    }
    function output() public view returns (string memory,uint,string memory)
    {
        return (dtl.name, dtl.id, dtl.post);
    }
}
```

Don,t know why this error is showing, please tell me where I'm making mistake..

from solidity:

```
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for parameter in function, but none was given.
  --> contracts/structure.sol:12:25:
   |
12 |     function setDetails(string a, uint b, string c) public**
                             ~~~~~~~~          ~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the data location for the input parameters of the `setDetails()` function must be either "memory" or "calldata", but none was specified.

In order to fix this issue, you need to specify the data location for the input parameters by adding the memory keyword before the variable type. For example:

```
function setDetails(string memory a, uint b, string memory c) public
```

Another thing you're doing wrong, in this line `dtl=Details('a' , b , 'c');` you are using single quotes('') to assign the value to the variable which is not correct. You should use double quotes("") to assign the value to the variable. Tthe correct way to assign the value to the variable is this:

```
dtl=Details(a , b , c);
```